Question about proof involving locally convex spaces

This is proposition 2.6 in chapter 4 of Conway's Functional Analysis. I understand all of this proof except for where it says (Why?) in the last paragraph. Can someone explain that part to me?
Edit (for closed question): not sure what additional context is needed. I'm reading some functional analysis on topological vector spaces and locally convex spaces to help with my research in Linear Dynamics. See Linear Chaos here for more details: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-2170-1

First of all, note that if $X$ is a topological vector space and if $\rho$ is a continuous seminorm on $X$, then you have by Proposition IV.1.3 that the set $\{x\in X : \rho (x) < 1\}$ is open in $X$. Then by scaling and translations, which are homeomorphisms, you have that for any $x_{0}\in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ the set $\{x\in X : \rho (x-x_{0}) < \varepsilon \}$ is open in $X$.
After defining the norm $p$ on $\mathscr{X}$, you now have two topologies on $\mathscr{X}$ to consider. One is the topology $\tau_{\mathscr{P}}$ generated by a given family of seminorms $\mathscr{P}$ which induce the locally convex topology on $\mathscr{X}$ and another topology $\tau_{p}$ which is generated by the norm $p$. As $p$ is continuous with respect to the topology $\tau_{\mathscr{P}}$ on $\mathscr{X}$, you have that the subbase of $\tau_{p}$ induced by $p$ is contained in $\tau_{\mathscr{P}}$ and consequently that $\tau_{p} \subseteq \tau_{\mathscr{P}}$. If you show that whenever $q$ is a continuous seminorm on $(\mathscr{X},\tau_{\mathscr{P}})$ there is some $\alpha > 0$ such that $q \leq \alpha p$, it follows from Proposition IV.1.3 that as $\alpha p$ is a continuous seminorm on $(\mathscr{X}, \tau_{p})$, $q$ is also a continuous seminorm on $(\mathscr{X}, \tau_{p})$. As this holds for all $q\in\mathscr{P}$, you have that the subbase of $\tau_{\mathscr{P}}$ induced by $\mathscr{P}$ is contained in $\tau_{p}$ and consequently that $\tau_{\mathscr{P}} \subseteq \tau_{p}$. As a result, if it is shown that for any continuous seminorm $q$ on $\mathscr{X}$ with respect to the original locally convex topology that there is some $\alpha > 0$ such that $q \leq \alpha p$, then the topology generated by the norm $p$ is the same as the original locally convex topology on $\mathscr{X}$.
For completeness, Proposition IV.1.3 in the book is stated below.

Proposition. Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a TVS and let $p$ be a seminorm on
$\mathscr{X}$. The following statements are equivalent.
(a) $p$ is continuous.
(b) $\{x\in \mathscr{X}: p(x) < 1 \}$ is open.
(c) $0 \in \text{int}\{x\in \mathscr{X}: p(x) < 1\}$.
(d) $0 \in \text{int}\{x\in \mathscr{X}: p(x) \leq 1\}$.
(e) $p$ is continuous at $0$.
(f) There is a continuous seminorm $q$ on $\mathscr{X}$ such that $p \leq q$.

